# Select data from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In a Select Query I want to get the results if the transaction type 1 exists it does not check the transaction type 3 otherwise it should select the transaction type 3.

Basically I have to select the customers who don't have refilled their account in a duration and have to expire their balance. But at registration time i am assigning initial balance which transaction type is 3. If customer didn't refill his account before that duration and have the initial balance which i have assigned at registration time i need to expire that balance as well.

```
SELECT customer.* FROM `customer` 
LEFT JOIN transaction ON (customer.ID=transaction.CUSTOMER_ID) 
WHERE transaction.CREATED_AT NOT Between '2013-02-06 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-05 23:59:59' 
AND transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID=1
AND transaction.transaction_status_id=3 AND customer.CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID=3 
GROUP BY customer.ID
```

This query works fine and give me records of the customer who didn't refill their account but when I add OR Transaction_type_id=3 it don't give the required result.

Comment: I want to get records of transaction type 1 if its there otherwise have to select the transaction type 3 if type 1 not found.

Comment: Can you provide a sqlfiddle instead of that github thingy?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the bracket when use the OR?

```
SELECT customer.* FROM `customer` 
LEFT JOIN transaction ON (customer.ID=transaction.CUSTOMER_ID) 
WHERE transaction.CREATED_AT NOT Between '2013-02-06 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-05 23:59:59' 
AND (transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID=1 OR transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID=3)
AND transaction.transaction_status_id=3 AND customer.CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID=3 
GROUP BY customer.ID
```

Comment: If so, could you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: it should not contain the 18 id customer as it has a refill in the above mentioned period. refereed to sample data.